# Web server unable to be accessed from external but from LAN ok

Tags: apache-2.2, php

Question: why I cannot access my webserver from external (public IP) meanwhile I can access it through my LAN. Error is cannot display page. Below is my server spec:

- OS FreeBSD v8.1
- Apache v2.2.17
- MySQL v5.1.54
- PHP v5.3.5

I have been looking answer for a week but still no solution. My webserver was working fine. I have done NAT IP properly in my firewall and looks good where others application server can serves as usual to external user.

I try  to telnet the web server's public IP to port 80 and everything looks fine to me. But question is why I still cannot access it from external using browser. Did I need to look into my php file or httpd.conf file or something that I,ve missing during installation? can pls someone help me on this, really appreciate.

Thanks

Comment: "from external (public IP)" means you try to access you web server from an external network?

Comment: yes. external means from external network or internet.

Comment: Can you find somthings in apache logs? If you stop apache, what happens?

Comment: In Apache logs (httpd-error.log) it shows request failed: error reading the headers. Meanwhile in (httpd-access.log) it show few lines "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 85 "-" "Wget/1.11.4". I try to wget from outside and result no data received.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to access your site from your internal lan via the external IP then it is probably a network issue.  If you are accessing it from outside your lan then it is likely the virtual host settings.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: I,m hosting only one domain for this web server. not multiple hostname or domains. do I need to config the vhosts settings? As for others web server I had also did not set the vhosts and its still works fine.